# Avoid hover effects on img and header hyperlinking from rest of the a's hover effects

Tags: html, css

On the menu item, I am hyperlinking a, I created a hover effect for that. But I do not want those hover effects for header and img hyperlinks. I want clean hyperlink on img, header without any hover effects.

HTML & css

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }        
      nav{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        height:110px;
      }        
       .menu ul{
        margin-left: 50px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;        
      }  
      .menu ul li {
        list-style: none;
      }
      .menu ul li img {
        display: block;
      }
      .menu ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        padding-right: 18px;
        padding-left: 18px;
        padding-top:14px;
        padding-bottom:14px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: black;
      }
      .menu ul li a:hover {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        background-color: #ff7504;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 18px;
        padding-right: 18px;
        padding-top:14px;
        padding-bottom:14px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .menu h1 {
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 44px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        line-height: 0.9;
      }
```

```html
 <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.jp/120x120.png" width="120px" height="120px">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="header" href="#"><h1>Sitename</h1></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">option1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">option2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">option3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">option4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Avoid hover effects on img and header hyperlinking from rest of the a's hover effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since :not selector method didn't work for you, I can think of 2 ways to do this.

1. Resetting The CSS manually for first and second hyperlink

```
    .menu ul li:nth-of-type(1) a:hover , .menu ul li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: black;

  }
```

Add this CSS below the hover effect CSS !

2. add classes to the hyperlinks you wanna add hover to and then edit those classes.

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.jp/120x120.png" width="120px" height="120px">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="header" href="#"><h1>Sitename</h1></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hoverMe">option1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hoverMe">option2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hoverMe">option3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hoverMe">option4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul li .hoverMe:hover {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    background-color: #ff7504;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

  }
```

I know there's probably a shorter  method to achieve it, But let me know it it helps !

Answer (score 2):

Your current selector

```
.menu ul li a:hover
```

says

> Whenever **any** anchor element inside a list item in an unordered list in an element with CSS class `.menu` is hovered, style the anchor according to the rules I'm giving you.

That is, as you described, not what you want. Instead, you only want certain links in that HTML structure to behave like that.

The easiest and best way to achieve that is to either exclude the ones you **don't** want the hover on by adding a CSS class to those,

```
.menu ul li a:not(.no-hover):hover
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 110px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li img {
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.menu ul li a:not(.no-hover):hover {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  background-color: #ff7504;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu h1 {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 44px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="no-hover">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/120x120.png" width="120px" height="120px">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="header no-hover" href="#">
        <h1>Sitename</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">option1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">option2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">option3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">option4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**or** by adding a CSS class to all of the links you **do** want the hover behaviour on:

```
.menu ul li .menulink:hover
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 110px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li img {
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.menu ul li a.menulink:hover {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  background-color: #ff7504;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu h1 {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 44px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/120x120.png" width="120px" height="120px">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="header" href="#">
        <h1>Sitename</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menulink">option1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menulink">option2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menulink">option3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menulink">option4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Because CSS has no way of styling elements based on their content/children, CSS class is what you typically use here.